# Backbone.js: Why can't I retrieve the model in this case?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to retrieve the model, because I need to access certain attributes, but I cannot. I'm inside a view, which extends another one. This is how the view looks like:

```
var ImageGridControlView = GridControlView.extend({
//.... stuff ....
alert(this.model.get('property')) //This gives me an error in console and nothing is alerted.
});
```

In the class that the above code extends, the model can be retrieved, like this:

```
var GridControlView = ControlView.extend({
//.... stuff ....
alert(this.model.get('property')) //This shows the property value correctly
});
```

Why can't the model be retrieved from ImageGridControlView? What is the persistence of models across different classes, children, etc? I'm new to Backbone, and the official documentation only covers models superficially.

Comment: I am not sure but have you tried using _.bindAll() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippets are too small to actually find the problem, so we have to just guess. Most likely candidates are:

- you are accessing `this.model` inside a function triggered by an event binding that is not properly bound, so `this` isn't actually your view instance. It could be a the source DOM element of the window object instead.
- You aren't passing a `model` property in the options object provided to the view's constructor

Comment: thanks... How can I know what the model is? Any way to check that? Any object that I can invoke, something to log to console?

Comment: The model is not automatic. You must pass it to the view's constructor in an options object. You can do `console.log(this.model)` but it's going to be `undefined` because you didn't define it. You still haven't posted a useful snippet. Do that.

Comment: I'd love to, but it's a big system, and I don't know what 'snippets' to post. There are hundreds of files, a lot of them calling, extending, and nesting with each other.

Comment: I accepted the answer, since the issue had to do with passing the model property when the view was constructed. Thanks!